# Malchus in Birkas Haminim

Tags: tefilla, shemoneh-esrei, birchat-haminim

Many nuschaos of Birkas Haminim say "Malchus Zadon" instead of "v'hazeidim" (this is the german nusach I believe as well as that used by some chasidim). Nusach Chabad also says Malchus HaRisha. How is this "Malchus" to be understood? Is it to be understood as a political Malchus (ie. The arrogant/wicked kingdom) or as a more metaphysical power of evil (ie. the kingship/sovereignty of arrogance/wickedness)?

Comment: ...כי תעביר ממשלת זדון מן הארץ

Comment: looks interesting and very relevant https://humanities.tau.ac.il/sites/humanities.tau.ac.il/files/media_server/Jewish%20History/Teuda/Teuda-%20Vol%2025/Teuda-%20Vol%2025-%2017-%20Tepler.pdf

Answer (score 3):

The nusach mentioning malchut is also found in the Sfardi text and appears in the ancient nusachot found in the Cairo Geniza.   Therefor it seems to me that on a simple pshat level the Malchut referred to in the original version is a reference to Rome, which makes sense from a historical perspective.
However within a kabbalistic context, Malchut ha Zadon or ha Risha is a reference to the Malcut of the Sitra Achra "זה כנגד זה ברא אלקים" And the prayer, in terms of kabbalistic kavanot, is intended to bring the aspect of Keter to the Malchut of Kedusha because that is the only one of the 10 sfirot that the Malchut of the Sitra Achra doesn't have access to. The Ari Z"L explains that until there was a predominance of heretics within the Jewish world this prayer was not needed. Which is why it was written at the time that Christianity began to become a problem.
The original nusach contained the words: "May the Nazarenes (ha-naẓarim/noṣrim/notzrim)[v][w] and the sectarians (minim) perish as in a moment".
The question is what we today should have in mind on a simple pshat level when referring in our prayers to the "Malchut ha Zadon" is a good question and I suppose the answer would depend on who you ask !

Comment: Welcome to MiYodeya Yiftach and thanks for this first answer. Since MY is different from other sites you might be used to, see [here](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) for a guide which might help understand the site. Great to have you learn with us!

Comment: Is it intended to be specified in this text whether Malchut of the Sitra Achra is Malchut of one of the four worlds of the Sitra Achra, or not in this text like in Lurianic writings? 

In other words, when it's not specified for Malchut of holiness, it usually refers to Malchut of Atzilut of holiness. So Malchut of the Sitra Achra, does this usually refer to Malchut of ____ of the Sitra, or not specified?

Answer (score 0):

The whole idea of the Keter of Nukva in the Sitra Achra is a very deep idea that requires much explanation.
It is beyond the scope of this site to be able to answer it thoroughly.  However in brief my understanding is that there are two aspects of Malchut.  The Malchut of which is active in the Hanhaga now is not the original Malchut.  The original Malchut has been concealed until the final redemption.   I have only found this idea discussed at length in the writings of R.Ashlag however the Vilna Goan also discusses it in his perush of the Sifra d'tzniuta.
I am not sure I understand the rest of your question because you are translating words into English and that changes the meaning.

Answer (score 0):

This is unambiguously and unequivocally a reference to Edom which in the days this bracha was formulated was understood to be the Roman Empire. This exile will end with the destruction of the Roman Empire and the eradication of the seed of Eisav. This is made clear in Daniel and Ovadiah.

The interesting question then becomes which power on the earth at this time is considered to be the Roman Empire. A strong candidate is the so called Holy See which today has official diplomatic relations with 184 sovereign states worldwide as a result of securing the Lateran treaty from the Kingdom of Italy under the leadership of Benito Mussolini.

The takeover of the Roman Empire by the so called Holy See began with the [Edict of Milan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edict_of_Milan) which gave the church legal status in the Roman Empire. The next stage of the takeover was the [Edict of Thessalonica](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edict_of_Thessalonica) which made the church the official religion of the Roman Empire.

From there on in it became much easier for the church to advance the antisemitism espoused by the likes of [John Chrysostom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Chrysostom) in Against the Jews.

Answer (score -1):

It applies to both the Malchut HaRisha *above*, meaning *Keter of Nukva of Rachel* and also to that which is sustained by it in this physical, material world.

For details, see the Siddur of Rabbi Shabtai of Rashkov, volume Weekday Shacharit, pp. 364-366.

Concerning the varying nusachot, see Siddur Rabbeinu HaZaken, pg. 141, note 234. It explains the changes were primarily due to concerns and fears about the censors.

Comment: The question was whether the phrase refers to the fact that evil is ruling or to the domain it rules over. This answer post doesn't seem to answer that.

Comment: @msh210 “How is this Malchus to be understood? Is it to be understood as a political Malchus...or as a more metaphysical power of evil?”

Comment: Please forgive if this is a bad question, but I'm not 100% on the term Malchut HaRisha. The Malchut of evil, like a rasha? If so I would ask a refresher why the Keter of the Nukva of Rachel is in the Sitra Achra in the Lurianic schema. Is it specified backs vs fronts in this case, or even the Keter of Nukva of Rachel is in the Sitra Achra because of the shattering of the vessels and the exile, despite her holiness? Sry Im having trouble wording it. 

Or does it mean the Malchut of beauty? Google says "Risha is Hebrew Girl name and meaning of this name is "Beautiful, Feather, Line, Saintly"

Comment: @ShipBuilding Did you look at the citation from the siddur of Rabbi Shabbtai of Rashkov? The explanation is there. FYI, Rabbi Google is not reliable. Regarding the source and relationship to Sitra Achra, see the concept of the doubling letters as explained by Rabbi Yosef Gikatilla, Sefer Ma’arechet Elokut and elsewhere in connection with Sefer Yetzirah.

Comment: @YaacovDeane I dont speak Hebrew so I have to look up the words. I cant even spell it in Hebrew so I type them in english letters into google. So not Rabbi Google, but Translator Google. 

I didnt look at the citations. I dont own those Siddurs at home, and this is what I get online: 

https://www.sefaria.org/search?q=Siddur%20Rabbeinu%20HaZaken&tab=text&tvar=1&tsort=relevance&svar=1&ssort=relevance

https://www.sefaria.org/search?q=Siddur%20of%20Rabbi%20Shabtai%20of%20Rashkov&tab=text&tvar=1&tsort=relevance&svar=1&ssort=relevance

Comment: @YaacovDeane Maybe if I could spell them in Hebrew they would come up. A lot of you most knowledgeable and experienced people on Mi Yodega, Rabbis and scholars for many years, know exactly where to find everything, and can do it without thinking, so putting myself in your shoes so to speak, it probably seems like I should be able to, but I don't have nearly as much experience with it. Not to mention 90% of the time I take the time to look up sources on sefaria, they're not available in english anyway.